# Could NOT find Discount (missing: Discount_LIBRARIES)

Tags: apt, package-management, compiling, cmake

I tried to compile Okular from source.

`cmake` complains that many things are missing. I manually search via Google for each error, or also via `apt search` and try to figure out the right Ubuntu package (very annoying process... is there some simpler way?).

So far I have: `cmake build-essential libqt5svg5-dev libkf5activities-dev libphonon4qt5-dev libtiff-dev libkf5purpose-dev libqt5texttospeech5-dev libpoppler-dev libpoppler-cpp-dev libpoppler-qt5-dev libfreetype-dev libspectre-dev libkf5kexiv2-dev libzip-dev libdjvulibre-dev libqmobipocket-dev libmarkdown2-dev libepub-dev libchm-dev`.

However, I'm stuck at this:

```
-- Checking for module 'libmarkdown'
--   No package 'libmarkdown' found
-- Could NOT find Discount (missing: Discount_LIBRARIES) 
-- Checking for module 'libmarkdown'
--   No package 'libmarkdown' found
-- Could NOT find Discount (missing: Discount_LIBRARIES) 
...

-- The following REQUIRED packages have not been found:

...
 * Discount, A library that gives you formatting functions suitable for marking down entire documents or lines of text, <https://www.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/Code/discount/>
   Support for Markdown documents in Okular. You can make the dependency optional adding Discount to the FORCE_NOT_REQUIRED_DEPENDENCIES cmake option
...
```

I already installed `libmarkdown2-dev` but this does not seem to help.
(I found this via `apt search Discount`.)

So, what do I need to install to resolve this error on the missing `Discount` library?

(Related: [Same problem for `LibSpectre`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413310/could-not-find-libspectre-missing-libspectre-library-libspectre-internal-found))

Answer (score 0):

Try the package search tool on https://packages.ubuntu.com ? Maybe what you're missing is the "Discount" package.

Your post was helpful - I was missing libmarkdown2-dev though the compile error only mentioned "Discount"!

Comment: Please reconsider your assessment of the answer being just a "thank you".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS (based on Ubuntu 22.04) was able to fix it by installing both `libmarkdown2-dev` and `discount`:

```
sudo apt install libmarkdown2-dev discount
```

I originally only installed the `discount` package, but [track0](https://askubuntu.com/users/1197550/track0)'s answer gave me the missing `libmarkdown2-dev` piece.

Comment: duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/1430271/